# Change text using bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a program called `gamemode`, and to check if it's running, you can use `gamemode -s`, which outputs either "gamemode is active" or "gamemode is inactive".

I want to change "gamemode is active" to "<an icon that doesn't show on this website>" and change "gamemode is inactive" to some other icon.

Answer (score 1):

sed would be easiest:

```
gamemode -s | sed -e 's/gamemode is active/<active icon>/' -e 's/gamemode is inactive/<inactive icon>/'
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great!

Comment: @Eysse if this answer works for you best, please accept it with the tick mark (✓)

Answer (score 0):

```
gamemode -s | awk '{print (/inactive/ ? <inactive icon> : <active icon>)}'
```